# Remove whitespace from ONLY last item in list

Tags: python

How do I remove only the last whitespace from this code? When I omit the `end=" "` in print, then it removes ALL the whitespace and I don't want that.

```
r = input("Line: ")
while True:
    n = r.split()
    if r == "":
      break  
    else:
      for word in n:
        print(word[::-1], end=" ")
      r = input("\nLine: ")
```

Without the `end=" "`, when I input `"hello world"`, it outputs `"ollehdlrow"`. When I add `end=" "` instead, it also prints an extra whitespace like this: `"olleh dlrow "`.

How can i obtain this: `"olleh dlrow"`?

Comment: What do you mean by "*removes all the whitespace*"?

Comment: in which when I input "hello world" to this code, it outputs "ollehdlrow" instead of "olleh dlrow". When I do this, however, it also gives an extra whitespace like this: "olleh dlrow "

Comment: This code is working for me...

Comment: your code is working, voting to close as it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: I reworded your question based on your comment because the request was not clear without those details.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of interposing a character between list values is with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print(' '.join(word[::-1] for word in n))
```

#### Example

```
>>> n = ['hello', 'world']
>>> ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in n)
'olleh dlrow'
```

#### Code improvements

Your code could be written like this:

```
while True:
    line = input("Line: ")
    if not line:
        break
    print(' '.join(word[::-1] for word in line.split()))
```

Comment: Is the question not asking how to not have whitespace between the words? In which case you will need `print(''.join(word[::-1] for word in n))`

Answer (score 0):

This is a specific behaviour of the `split()` function. So for doing what you want, you want to split on `' '`. See the difference between the following code snippets:

```
In [10]: 'this is a    test'.split()
Out[10]: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']

In [11]: 'this is a    test'.split(' ')
Out[11]: ['this', 'is', 'a', '', '', '', 'test']
```

For getting rid of the end whitespaces, you need to use `rstrip()` function. So you should do:

```
In [12]: 'this is a    test    '.rstrip(' ').split(' ')
Out[12]: ['this', 'is', 'a', '', '', '', 'test']
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> s='Hello there big     fella!'
>>> re.sub(r'([^\s]+)', lambda x: x.group(1)[::-1], s)
'olleH ereht gib     !allef'
```